# Get the number of assembly instructions at a certain fragment of code as compile-time constant

Tags: c++, c, gcc, llvm

I want to get the number of assembly instructions a certain segment of the code contains as a **compile time constant**.
I know how to get the desired value at runtime but have no idea how to get compile time constant for it. I mainly target LLVM (and GCC) and can use any compiler-specific tricks.

```
int foo(int* a, int* b, int* c) {
    char* l1_ptr = &&l1;
    char* l2_ptr = &&l2;
    long num_asm_instructions = l2_ptr - l1_ptr;
    l1:
    asm goto("" :::: l1, l2);
    c[0] = a[0] + b[0];
    c[1] = a[1] + b[1];
    c[2] = a[2] + b[2];
    asm goto("" :::: l1, l2);
    l2:
    //asm("" :: "i"(num_asm_instructions));  // how to make this possible?
    return num_asm_instructions;
}
```

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/Tj1occa4E

Comment: Isn't it just number of bytes for the l2_ptr - l1_ptr? Some instructions cost 1 byte, some cost 15 bytes.

Comment: First thing, on an x86 the assembly instructions have different sizes, so counting bytes doesn't help. The compiler is alos not required to put them in any specific order, counting the bytes doesn't help much either.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I think the number of bytes would be enough for me. I would be happy with any of them: the number of bytes or the number of instructions. I hope this makes things easier.

Comment: What do you need this information for? Because if you look for an indicator for performance : the number of assembly instruction does not really say much about peformance. Only about the size of memory to store those instructions in.

Answer (score 1):

Compile a sample object. Count instructions or bytes generated by compiler. From that, generate a header file to compile with the count.

The following files:

```
==> main.c <==
#include "numasminstructions.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        printf("%d\n", NUM_ASM_INSTRUCTIONS);
}


==> numasminstructions.c <==
void count_number_of_instructions(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
        asm("nop");
    c[0] = a[0] + b[0];
    c[1] = a[1] + b[1];
    c[2] = a[2] + b[2];
        asm("nop");
}


==> compile.sh <==
#!/bin/bash
set -xeuo pipefail
gcc -O -c numasminstructions.c
count=$(
        objdump -S numasminstructions.o |
                tee /dev/stderr |
        sed '/nop$/,/nop$/!d' |
        wc -l
)
echo "#define NUM_ASM_INSTRUCTIONS $((count - 2))" > numasminstructions.h
gcc main.c
./a.out
```

Running `./compile.sh` outputs:

```
+ gcc -O -c numasminstructions.c
++ objdump -S numasminstructions.o
++ tee /dev/stderr
++ sed '/nop$/,/nop$/!d'
++ wc -l

numasminstructions.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <count_number_of_instructions>:
   0:   90                      nop
   1:   8b 06                   mov    (%rsi),%eax
   3:   03 07                   add    (%rdi),%eax
   5:   89 02                   mov    %eax,(%rdx)
   7:   8b 46 04                mov    0x4(%rsi),%eax
   a:   03 47 04                add    0x4(%rdi),%eax
   d:   89 42 04                mov    %eax,0x4(%rdx)
  10:   8b 46 08                mov    0x8(%rsi),%eax
  13:   03 47 08                add    0x8(%rdi),%eax
  16:   89 42 08                mov    %eax,0x8(%rdx)
  19:   90                      nop
  1a:   c3                      ret
+ count=11
+ echo '#define NUM_ASM_INSTRUCTIONS 9'
+ gcc main.c
+ ./a.out
9
```

The same method, with proper parsing of `objdump -S` output or by writing an ELF parser yourself, can be used to count instructions or bytes in any arbitrary region of code.

Comment: This is a good idea but I see the problem: the number of instructions counted this way may not match the real number of instructions I had initially. This may break certain assumptions I need to rely on. This actually happens here: there should be 9 instructions (3 loads, 3 adds, 3 stores) but you counted 37.

Comment: Yes. If I don't find a simpler solution, I'll probably have to do it.

Comment: I think the exact number depends not only on the compiler but also on the location in the code you put it and enabled optimizations. This is why I am trying to avoid doing two-pass implementation as it is hard to make sure that both sources will result in the same assembly.

Comment: You can't get the exact result anyway. Full compilation AND linking will be the closest you can get.